# meteor.js where to put js code for dom manipulation

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am curious where to put my code for DOM manipulation. Like some events on form submit etc.

Because when i put them to the:

```
Template.friendRow.rendered = function() {  
   function sendMessage() {
     console.log("Message sent");
   }
   $(document).on('submit', 'form.sendMessageForm', sendMessage);
}
```

In console i see 2x "Message sent".

Why and how to fix it or where to put the code?

Comment: You should probably try to avoid doing DOM manipulation as much as possible and depend on reactive rendering to do the work. It will save you much effort as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.rendered()` is not a right place for form submission. It is a callback that is called every time when the template is rendered or re-rendered.

Move your form handling code to any `click` event handler that is associated with form submission. 
e.g

```
'click #submit_btn' : function(){
   // your form submission code
}
```

See http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps.

Comment: Ow i just remember! But it need to be placed here: Template.name.events :) Thx for remembering me :)